# Not able to concat two sentences in Java

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

I wanted to concat two two strings.

This is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution { 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 4;
        double d = 4.0;
        String s = "HackerRank ";       
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);    
        int a; double b;  String c;
        a = scan.nextInt();
        b = scan.nextDouble();
        c = scan.next();
        System.out.println(i + a);
        System.out.println(d + b);
        String res = s.concat(c);
        System.out.println(res);       
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

Input:

```
12
4.0
is the best place to learn and practice coding!
```

This output:

```
16
8.0
HackerRank is
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDgUC.png)

I tried everything I can think of.

Comment: This code won't even compile.  You are assigning scan.next() to c, and c is not declared.

Comment: Can you share the HackerRank link @Ravi Kumar'

Comment: link: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-data-types/problem @Jarvis

Comment: i have edited it, still not working @JohnCzukkermann

Comment: At least it will run now!  It isn't working because you are printing i+a first, then d+b, then the concatenation of "HackerRank " + c.  Why would you think it would do anything different than what you are telling to do.

You haven't told use what output you expect to get.

To concatenate two strings:

String s = "a ";
String t = "b ";
String u = "c!";
String v = s + t + u:

There are several ways to concatenate strings in Java.  That is just one way.  You can use concat too.  You can use StringBuilder's append method too.

Comment: see my edits @Ravi Kumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**

If you change to `nextLine()`, the previous inputs don't consume the newline character, so you'll have to add in an extra `scan.nextLine();`.

[See demo online](https://ideone.com/8afwRh)

---

First, declare `c` (i.e. `String c`), and also `a` and `b` (or maybe you did it but forgot to put it in your post?)

But then, your problem is using [`Scanner::next`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()) instead of [`Scanner::nextLine`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()).

`.next()` from the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()):

> Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner.

`.next()` takes the first token, using whitespace as the delimiter, so that's why your output is `HackerRank is`, assuming your `c` is holding something like `is a great site`.

**Solution**

Change:

`c = scan.next();` to `c = scan.nextLine();`

Comment: still not working
output:
    16
    8.0
    HackerRank

Comment: @RaviKumar it would be easier to help if you showed your actual code and the input you entered.

Comment: @RaviKumar see my edit there at the top. It fixes your issue.

Comment: thanks 
i didn't understood why are we using extra

    scan.nextLine();
@achAmháin

Answer (score 0):

Here you go..

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 4;
        double d = 4.0;
        String s = "HackerRank ";
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = scan.nextInt();
        double b = scan.nextDouble();
        scan.nextLine();
        String c = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println(i + a);
        System.out.println(d + b);
        String res = s + c;
        System.out.println(res);
        scan.close();


    }
}
```

and see below result:  [image: successfully accepted result:]

> That's because the Scanner.nextInt or nextDouble method does not consume the last
>   newline character of your input, and thus that newline is consumed in
>   the next call to Scanner.nextLine

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class ScannerDemo
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int i = 4;
        double d = 4.0;
        String s = "HackerRank ";
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = scan.nextInt();
        double b = scan.nextDouble();
        scan.nextLine();
        String c = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println(i + a);
        System.out.println(d + b);
        String res = s.concat(c);
        System.out.println(res);
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

Your Input needs to be

```
12
4.0
is the best place to learn and practice coding!
```

Output will be:

```
16 8.0 HackerRank is the best place to learn and practice coding!
```

Answer (score 0):

Scan an extra line before scanning the c. 
Like

```
scan.nextLine();
c = scan.nextLine();
```

Because before entering c you press enter, there takes a line input.

Answer (score -1):

```
int a = scan.nextInt();
double b = scan.nextDouble();
String c = scan.next();
```

you have to define this variable like I do

Comment: I would say this isn't the main problem, as the OP is getting an output, and it wouldn't compile if they didn't declare the variables.

Comment: i have decalred the variables, just forgot to copy that line